# All users in same profile are able to access the custom button made of Vf page but one user is unable to:

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, profile, user

All users in the same profile are able to access a custom button made of a visual force page except one user. when this user hits the button the below error has been occurring.

**Unable to Access Page
The value of the "id" parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information.**

Can some please guide me the resolution.

Thanks In Advance
Ven

Comment: What URL are they browsing to after the custom button is clicked?  Sounds like you need to talk with the user and ask them for a screen grab of the error, including the URL.  Looks to me like the button is generating a URL with an id parameter that is longer than 18 characters.

Comment: Hi James.. thanks for your reply. Actually the URL is same for this user and other users. https://cs1.salesforce.com/apex/CustomSendToZBillingPage?scontrolCaching=1&id=a2jS0000000pzbN This is the URL for the user whos getting error...This is the URL for other USERS: https://cs1.salesforce.com/apex/CustomSendToZBillingPage?scontrolCaching=1&id=a2jS0000000pyAH

Comment: Hm..... I still cant see this. Could you please edit your question and provide us with some code

Comment: I have a custom button on a detail page. That is made of a vf page. The user with name: Saniol Allen. he was in different profile before. From that profile he was unable to access this button. so I have assigned him in the different profile whwre users are able to access this button. However, even in the new profile he is unable to access this button and getting above error. at the same time other users are able to access.